# Why the login_required decorator doesn't work?

Tags: python, django

Working on a simple project using Django 3.2 and the loqin_required decorator is not working.
When I close the server and re-open it again, it works the first time but not anymore.
It used to work very well, but I'm not sure what I changed in the code that it doesn't work anymore.

views.py

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Count
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages

from .models import *
from .models import __str__
from .forms import CreateUserForm

# Create your views here.

@login_required(login_url='login/')
def home(request):
    count_item = todo.objects.count()
    
    all_items = todo.objects.all().order_by("created")

    context = {'all_items': all_items, 'count_item':count_item}

    return render(request, 'html/home.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login/')
def add_todo(request):
    current_date = timezone.now()
    new_item= todo(content = request.POST["content"])
    new_item.save()
    return redirect('/')

@login_required(login_url='login/')
def delete_todo(request, todo_id):
    item_to_delete = todo.objects.get(id=todo_id)
    item_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('/')

def login_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        # print('USER:', user)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/') 
    return render(request, 'html/login.html')


def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login/')

def register_user(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(request, username=user.username, password=request.POST.get('password1'))

            print("USER:",user)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'html/register.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from . import views


app_name = 'todo'




urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('add_todo/', views.add_todo),
    path('delete_todo/<int:todo_id>/', views.delete_todo),
    path('login/', views.login_user, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.register_user, name="register"),
]
```

Any suggestion or response would appreciate it
Thanks!

Comment: What does your `logOut` view looks like?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What behaviour are you observing and expecting?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the logout view just redirect the user to the login page(home page), its just the function

Comment: @Zani123: but it needs to remove the session data, to ensure that the user logs out properly, a redirect is *not* sufficient.

Comment: @Zani123 are you calling `logout(request)` from the `django.contrib.auth` module within your logout view? Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out

Comment: @IainShelvignton the decorator is not working, I'm expecting for the user to not have access to the home page when it is logged out.

Comment: @bob yes, im calling ```logout(request)```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can I do it right?

Comment: @Zani123: share the `logOut` view you have right now...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i did it

Comment: @Zani123 there is no problem with the current version of django login decorators (I just tested them to make sure) so it's either related to your imports, your html/javascript or your browser/settings.

Comment: @bob when I first open it at a new browser, it works, but after I log in and I log out, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Zani123 perhaps you should try in a different clean installed (no plugins) browser, ensure its actually making requests to your endpoints and not returning cached results. Ensure in your django server log that your endpoints are being requested. If all that fails then step debug your endpoints. If that fails try deleting your venv and recreating it with your requirements for the project, if you have many modules try enabling them one at a time as one of them could be outdated and causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging out the user just by redirecting, you're not actually logging them out. You have to use the logout function of the authentication framework, with the logout() function, or you can use logout_then_login view from django if all you want to do is send users back to the login page.